# GCM push notifications not received in certain android devices

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app in android. It uses gcm notification. Its working well but only on 8 devices out of 10. when i test for notification forwats-app on those 2 devices  they are working fine for wats-app.Any But in my app at PHP end it shows success but  my app did not receive any notification (2 cases). Any suggestion should be appreciated.

Comment: there are some devices which does not support GCM. which one are you using?

Comment: thanks for response. but whats app working on thosew devices

Comment: im not sure, but there are some chinese devices which does only support other solutions you can search it with google Push notification android

Comment: may you please suggest other solution, i am unable to getting

Comment: are those devices are chinese?

Comment: yes both are chinese

Comment: Ok, please look on my answer below

Comment: i have visited given link but most benificial for me is open push notification but it is still in beta mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some devices which does not support GCM And Google play store.

Alternatives can be found here: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825121/android-push-notifications-in-china)

Hope this help you :)